# A Lottery Solidity Smart Contract that accept erc20/bep20 token instead of ether to enter the lottery

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, erc-20

```
  function enter() public payable {
    require(msg.value > .01 ether);

    players.push(msg.sender);
  }
```

Change this function to accept erc20/bep20 token to enter the lottery

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish the address(es) of the tokens to accept and then use the Approve and TransferFrom pattern.

```
include "IERC20.sol";

contract Lotto {

  address public token;

  constructor(address token_) {
    token = token_;
  }

  function enter(unit amount) public payable {
    require(amount > .01 ether);
    // it is assumed that the UI already prompted the user to approve this transferFrom
    IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, amount);
    players.push(msg.sender);
  }
```

Special note: If accepting arbitrary tokens (you can't confirm the contracts are well-behaved before hand), then wrap the IERC20 interface with SafeERC20 from openzeppelin where you also get the IERC20 interface.

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there an example for that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/willianmano/eac9b24ff9df04cce88465f485a8fdbc this is the contract that I want to change the ether to erc20 as fee for lottery.

Comment: @RobHitchens can you elaborate more on this topic.. I am trying to send the ERC20 token to the address of a contract.

Comment: The user interface does a two-step. First, the user sends an "approve" transaction to the token contract to authorize the receiver contract to draw from the user's account a certain amount of tokens. Then, the user transacts with the receiver contract and it pulls funds from the user's address in the token contract. This is contingent on the first step. If there is no pre-approved allowance, it will fail, by design.